# Nodejs include public folder in package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, server

I want to deploy a nodejs server on Heroku via Dropbox. The server app requires a public folder named "static" to exist in the host root.

Can the folder be created when the dependencies are installed from the package.json? Or are there any other means?

Comment: You can [do a lot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634349/heroku-npm-postinstall-script-to-run-grunt-task-depending-on-enviro) through [post-install scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)